# How to integrate $ \int\limits_0^\infty{\frac{1}{{\sqrt {({y_1} - {y_2}){y_2}} }}d{y_2}} $?

Tags: probability

I tried to do but it does not exist.

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty{\frac{1}{{\sqrt {({y_1} - {y_2}){y_2}} }}d{y_2}} $$

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean integration with respect to $y_2$ where $y_1$ is some constant, or what?

Comment: yes y1 is constant

Comment: I suggest change the variable names as $y_1\to a$ and $y_2\to x$ for making it more clear what the difference is

Answer (score 1):

The function you are trying to integrate does not exist on the whole $\mathbb R^+$, because the radicand will sooner or later become negative. This implies that the integral is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The function is undefined on $y_2\ge y_1$ and $y_2\le0$ and integration assumes the function is continuous on the given domain, and if the function is not defined on some of the domain it is definitely not continuous at those points.